# How to design a partial function that accepts the all domain, but dependent on some state?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

A functional programming related question.

"One line of code is worth a thousand words", so:

```
class Entry {
  var entryOrderId: Option[Int]
  def closeEntry(closeOrder: Order) = {
    require(entryOrderId.isDefined)
    ...
  }
}
```

The question: in order to close an entry, the entryOrderId must be defined. I don't want to throw an exception (using the 'require' function) and I prefer not to return a Try (Success/Failure) object, because the caller doesn't expect any return value. How would you design this function?

(N.b: I tagged Scala, but the language is not the matter here...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your requirements, if the caller truly does not care about the result, then you can just use `foreach` on the `entryOrderId`. So the inner block will only be called if `entryOrderId` is defined.

```
class Entry {
  var entryOrderId: Option[Int]
  def closeEntry(closeOrder: Order) = entryOrderId foreach { id =>
    // do something with the `id` ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that is actually the answer. I didn't ask the right question, though. The caller does need its request for `closeOrder` to be filled, I just didn't want to check it every time. I think I'll just change the design a little bit, so I'll never have an entry without `entryOrderId`... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If calling `closeEntry` on an entry that has no entryOrderId is a programming error, it should not even compile. To enforce this, I would add a type parameter on `Entry`. That will make the state change explicit, as well as the constraints on the state of your Entry required by closeEntry.

```
class Order
case class Entry[T <: Option[Int]](entryOrderId: T) {
  def closeEntry(closeOrder: Order)(implicit ev: T =:= Some[Int]): Unit = {
    entryOrderId.get + 42
  }
}
```

The compiler will complain if you call closeEntry on `Entry[Option[Int]]` or `Entry[None.type]`:

```
scala> Entry(Some(42)).closeEntry(new Order)

scala> Entry(None).closeEntry(new Order)
<console>:11: error: Cannot prove that None.type =:= Some[Int].
              Entry(None).closeEntry(new Order)
                                    ^
```

This solution is far from perfect:

- The type of Entry is unnecessarily verbose (the `Int` is too much)
- I don't know how to extract an `Entry[Some[Int]]` from a `Entry[Option[Int]]` using pattern matching, so you'd better not lose the type information once you get an `Entry[Some[Int]]`
- Other issues I didn't see :p

Of all the variations to this, the best I've been able to find is:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

class Order
case class Entry[T[_]](entryOrderId: T[Int]) {
  def closeEntry(order: Order)(implicit withId: WithId[T]): Unit = {
    withId.getId(this) + 42
  }
}
implicit object Entry extends HasId[Some] {
  def getId(entry: Entry[Some]): Int = entry.entryOrderId.get
}

trait WithId[T[_]] {
  def getId(entry: Entry[T]): Int
}
```

(better because the type is now a bit shorter – `Entry[Some]` instead of `Entry[Some[Int]]`)

---

Another, much simpler solution is:

```
sealed trait Entry
case class EntryWithId(val entryOrderId: Int) extends Entry {
  def closeEntry(closeOrder: Order): Unit = {
    ...
  }
}
class NewEntry() extends Entry
```

The only problem is that you have to copy-paste the constructors for other eventual fields.

Comment: The problem is, sorry for didn't mention, is that entryOrderId is set on runtime, therefore I cannot check it on compilation. Many thanks, anyway!